# Java Objects for Time

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, time

I have to make a class named "Time" with the following

- data fields hours, minute, and second.
- no-arg constructor that creates a Time object for the current time.
- constructor that constructs a "Time" object with specified elapsed time since Jan. 1, 1970 in milliseconds. (Values from data fields will represent this time)
- constructor that constructs a "Time" object with specified hour,minute, and second.
- 3 methods for data fields, hour, minute, and second.
- method named "setTime(long elapsedTime) that sets a new time for the object using the elapsed time.

Currently I think I have a solid method down to convert the milliseconds obtained from System.currentTimeMillis() to hours/minutes/seconds.
As '(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000*60*60)) % 24 would be the hours
   (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000*60)) % 60 would be minutes
   (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60 would be seconds`

I'm currently confused on how to implement this into the assignment, I know its a broad question asking for some sort of guidelines that might steer in me into the right direction because I'm not very familiar with objects and feel pretty lost at the moment. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'll update the post if I can if I make any progress.

Comment: Are you allowed use java's built-in [Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)? Read its javadocs and see how much of that work is already done for you. Just [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) all the work to Date. (links in this comment; hard to see but they're there!)

Comment: I recognized this. This is a school assignment. I had assigned similar work to my students when I was teaching.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading over both links (Date class and delegate). Would I just be using "public getHours()" to get the current hours on a clock example 8 hours for 8:20pm? Also there is a part on that says "For the no-arg constructor, the current time can be obtained using System.currentTimeMillis()" I know what it shows current time, but what exactly is a "no-arg constructor" and would I have any issues if I used Date class because it seems very useful if I'm understanding everything correctly. Thanks for the help also!

Comment: Why don' you post what code you have written and let us point you in the right direction.

Comment: @NovaLeLeague is this from Y. Daniel Liang's *Intro to Java* book by any chance?

Comment: @hfontanez I believe our professor gave of a problem similar from examples in the book, but not directly in the book. We are using Daniel Liang's Intro to Java though, I've tried going over the circle and TV examples from it and seem to understand it, but as soon as I try to implement it I seem to just go blank.

Comment: The problem is from the book. I have given that on assignments before which is why I recognized it.  If you post the code you have, I will be more than glad to help you through it. After all, I know EXACTLY what the answer is.

Comment: @hfontanez Okay, thank you currently my code is pretty lackluster as I keep scrapping it, I've been reading the book and googling for the past few hours as I try to make sense of it, it seems really simple but I just can't seem to get it down on paper. If you would like I can post what I have, but at the moment its only automated getters and setters from eclipse from hours,minute,seconds. I have a few notes written down in a notepad that I've been sort of noting things each time I scrapped my previous attempts. Sorry long reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: This is the class you have to create for your assignment.]
The no-arg constructor takes System.currentTimeMillis() and invokes the second constructor using `this()`. This other constructor in turn, calls the `setTime()` method.  This is the method that extracts the second, minutes, and hours from that `long` argument (elapsed time).  The third constructor simply sets the hour, minute, and second data members.  There are three getter methods as you can see, and a toString method that creates a String in the HH:MM:SS format. This should be more than enough information for you to complete the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, break the problem into small parts. Are you comfortable creating a class with the three fields and getters/setters for them? Then do that first.

Then you can add a setTime(long) method to the class. In that class, use your method to calculate hours, minutes and seconds like you described (I didn't check if your method looked like it was going to work correctly but let's just assume that). Once you have the hours, minutes and seconds in variables inside the setTime(long) method, you can call your setHours(), setMinutes() and setSeconds() methods that you previously created.

Once you have that method, then you can create your constructors. The millisecond constructor can just call your setTime() method. The parameterless one can call System.currentTimeMillis() and use the output of that to call setTime(). The one that takes hours, minutes and seconds can simply just call the setXXX() methods for your fields directly.

Comment: Thanks this helped quite a bit, so I made a class and had long type variables for hour,minute,seconds and used eclipse's feature for getters and setters, would I then add the setTime method you mentioned below my getters and setters section that was created?

Comment: hour, minute, and second don't need to be primitive longs.

Comment: Order doesn't matter (much) when you're writing a class. You can put the methods and constructors in any order you like them to be. Grouping methods together logically is a good idea though, it makes your class easier to read.

Comment: And as mentioned, long type variables for hours minutes and seconds is overkill. Well, technically, hours could become infinitely big so sure, use long for that... but minutes and seconds should never be more than 60 so you can use a smaller primitive such as short or int. You can even use a byte for those if you want to since, as I mentioned, they'll never exceed 60.